# The component didn't catch the updated error message from the service

Tags: angular, typescript, service, observable, subscribe

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
  error$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(
    private errorService: ErrorHandlerService
  ) {
     this.errorService.errorPublic.subscribe((errorres) => {
      console.log('Component subscribed to error: ' + errorres);
      if (errorres) {
        this.error$ = of(errorres);
      }
    });}
```

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ErrorHandlerService {
  private errorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string | null>(null);
  public errorPublic: Observable<string | null> =
    this.errorSubject.asObservable();

  handleError(error: any) {
    let errorMessage = 'An unknown error occurred';
 
    this.errorSubject.next(errorMessage);
    console.log(errorMessage);
    console.error(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

1. Component subscribed to error: null         Component.component.ts:35
2. POST localhost:8080/auth/login 401 (Unauthorized)
3. HTTP Error: Wrong password                  errorHandler.service.ts:37
4. HTTP Error: Wrong password                  errorHandler.service.ts:39

I am trying to implement error handling in my Angular component. After the component is opened, the constructor handles its initialization, and I receive my first point with the variable 'null' correctly set.

Next, I send a bad request and receive point 2. Then, I attempt to update my errorSubject via errorPublic and send it to my error$ in the component. At this point, I encounter a problem because, as we can see, I receive both console logs from ErrorService, but my component doesn't display something like this:

> 1. Component subscribed to error: An unknown error occurred Component.component.ts:35

My component isn't receiving the updated value from errorSubject, and I'm unable to display this information on the layout.

Edit:

```
  private errorSubject = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
  public errorPublic: Observable<string> = this.errorSubject.asObservable();

  public testError: string;
  constructor() {
    this.errorPublic.subscribe((error) => {
      this.testError = error;
      console.log('error from service info: ' + this.testError);
    });
  }
```

error from service info: HTTP Error: Wrong  errorHandler.service.ts:23

When I place this subscription in the constructor of my service, it logs information about changes to the console, but my component didn't:

```
 constructor() {
   this.errorService.errorPublic.subscribe((error) => {
      this.error = error;
      console.log('error from component: ' + this.error);
    });
}
```

Comment: why do you have `error$` and `errorPublic`? I don't think you need `error$`. maybe you should use a `ReplySubject(1)` instead of `BehaviorSubject` so you don't have to filter for `null`

Comment: I changed it to ReplaySubject(1), but I am still facing issues. I use error$ because I display errors for the user, and it is a variable in my HTML component.